# How to Show categories on BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

Is it possible to show specific categories in BigCommerce instead of all categories?

We have used the code `%%Panel.SideCategoryList%%` but it shows all the categories.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

At this time there is not a way to uniquely control the output of categories using that panel. Depending on your context, you can either
1. Allow all categories to be output and use javascript to selectively hide a few (this is far from ideal, I know).
2. Manually add the categories into that panel and skip the dynamic category insertion.

Answer (score 0):

In the admin, click on Products, then click Product Categories. That page displays all of the categories for your site. On the right of the page you'll see green checkmarks. If you don't want a category to be visible on your site, simply click the green checkmark and it will turn into a red X